# Fixing the form of a table

Tags: tables

I am writing the below to get a table... Once I build it, there's something that doesn't look good... I can't figure out how to fix it !
Please help :)

```
 \documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper,fleqn]{report}
  \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{booktabs}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{multicol}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|rrrrrr|}
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{w} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$c_1$} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$c_2$} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$c_3$} \\ 
       & {$\tilde{d}_{1,w}$} & {$pr_{1,w}$ }& {$\tilde{d}_{2,w}$} & {$pr_{2,w}$} & {$\tilde{d}_{3,w}$} & {$pr_{3,w}$} \\
  \hline
H & 140 & 0.35 & 110 & 0.3 & 270 & 0.55\\
A & 190& 0.5 & 220 & 0.4& 350 & 0.1 \\
C & 380 & 0.15 & 650 & 0.3 & 800 & 0.35 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{bla}\label{t2}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The third `\multicolumn` specification misses the vertical line:

```
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{$c_3$} \\
```

> [image: Result]

And the variant with `booktabs` without vertical lines
(also `multirow` is not necessary) follows. The numbers are aligned and set via package `siunitx`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper,fleqn]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{bla}\label{t2}
    \begin{tabular}{
      l
      S[table-format=3.0]
      S[table-format=1.2]
      S[table-format=3.0]
      S[table-format=1.1]
      S[table-format=3.0]
      S[table-format=1.2]
    }
      \toprule
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$c_1$}
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$c_2$}
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$c_3$}
      \\
      \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
      \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
      \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
      $w$
      & {$\tilde{d}_{1,w}$} & {$pr_{1,w}$}
      & {$\tilde{d}_{2,w}$} & {$pr_{2,w}$}
      & {$\tilde{d}_{3,w}$} & {$pr_{3,w}$}
      \\
      \midrule
      H & 140 & 0.35 & 110 & 0.3 & 270 & 0.55 \\
      A & 190 & 0.5  & 220 & 0.4 & 350 & 0.1  \\
      C & 380 & 0.15 & 650 & 0.3 & 800 & 0.35 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result booktabs]

Comment: Thank you!!! Is this the best/standard way to write such a table, if I may ask?

Comment: @Selena I have updated the answer to include a variant, which uses `booktabs` (you have already loaded the package) without the unprofessional vertical lines and which uses `siunitx` for the numbers, aligned at the decimal marker.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two possibilities. I don't think `multirow` is useful here. I fromatted some numerical columns with the `siunitx` package.
In the version with vertical lines, I added some vertical padding with the `cellspace` package. In my opinion, the version without vertical lines looks better, using the rule commands from `booktabes (which incorporate some vertical padding around rules):

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper,fleqn]{report}
 \usepackage{booktabs}
 \usepackage{cellspace}
 \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
 \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
 \usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{table-format=1.2, table-number-alignment=center}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|Cl|rSrS[table-format=1.1]rS|}
    \hline
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$c_1$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$c_2$} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$c_3$} \\
    w & {$\tilde{d}_{1,w}$} & {$pr_{1,w}$ } & {$\tilde{d}_{2,w}$} & {$pr_{2,w}$} & {$\tilde{d}_{3,w}$} & {$pr_{3,w}$} \\[0.5ex]
    \hline
    H & 140 & 0.35 & 110 & 0.3 & 270 & 0.55 \\
    A & 190 & 0.5 & 220 & 0.4 & 350 & 0.1 \\
    C & 380 & 0.15 & 650 & 0.3 & 800 & 0.35 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{bla}\label{t2}
\end{table}
\vskip1cm
\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lrSrS[table-format=1.1]rS}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$c_1$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$c_2$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$c_3$} \\
    w & {$\tilde{d}_{1,w}$} & {$pr_{1,w}$ } & {$\tilde{d}_{2,w}$} & {$pr_{2,w}$} & {$\tilde{d}_{3,w}$} & {$pr_{3,w}$} \\[0.5ex]
    \cmidrule(l{0.3em}r{0.3em}){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-7}
    H & 140 & 0.35 & 110 & 0.3 & 270 & 0.55 \\
    A & 190 & 0.5 & 220 & 0.4 & 350 & 0.1 \\
    C & 380 & 0.15 & 650 & 0.3 & 800 & 0.35 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{bla}\label{t2}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]